# How to convert multiple string formats into one date format in BigQuery?

Tags: date, casting, google-bigquery, formatdatetime

I have a date column say "payment date" in my data which has multiple string formats such as `ddmmyyyy`,`ddmyyyy` and `yyyymmdd`. Does anyone know how I can convert all of these into a unified date format like `dd-mm-yyyy` in BigQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT payment_date, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', CASE LENGTH(payment_date) 
    WHEN 7 THEN 
      SAFE.DATE(
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, -4) AS INT64), 
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, 3, 1) AS INT64), 
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, 1, 2) AS INT64)
      )    
    WHEN 8 THEN 
      CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_ddmmyyyy) > 2000 THEN date_ddmmyyyy
        ELSE date_yyyymmdd
      END    
    ELSE NULL
  END) formatted_payment_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST([STRUCT<date_ddmmyyyy DATE, date_yyyymmdd DATE>(
    SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y', payment_date), 
    SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', payment_date)
  )])
```

You can test and play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standradSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '11112011' payment_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,    '1112011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,    '20111111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,    '20112011' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,    '20110228'
)
SELECT id, payment_date, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', CASE LENGTH(payment_date) 
    WHEN 7 THEN 
      SAFE.DATE(
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, -4) AS INT64), 
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, 3, 1) AS INT64), 
        SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(payment_date, 1, 2) AS INT64)
      )    
    WHEN 8 THEN 
      CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_ddmmyyyy) > 2000 THEN date_ddmmyyyy
        ELSE date_yyyymmdd
      END    
    ELSE NULL
  END) formatted_payment_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  UNNEST([STRUCT<date_ddmmyyyy DATE, date_yyyymmdd DATE>(
    SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y', payment_date), 
    SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', payment_date)
  )])
ORDER BY id
```

with result as:

```
Row id  payment_date    formatted_payment_date   
1   1   11112011        11-11-2011   
2   2   1112011         11-01-2011   
3   3   20111111        11-11-2011   
4   4   20112011        20-11-2011   
5   5   20110228        28-02-2011
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with below combination, can you help with similar logic.

21/02/22 18:00
21/2/2022 18:00
21/2/2022 6:00